# What does the "[ffmpeg] tls: Failed to send close message" error mean (mpv)?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl, mpv

I often stream video or audio in mpv (requires youtube-dl, FFmpeg is installed) and the `[ffmpeg] tls: Failed to send close message` error is always displayed in shell (PowerShell) when I quit the application.

What implications does this error have and is it even directly related to to mpv?

---

Windows 10 64-bit, mpv 0.29.1

Comment: Are you experiencing any *actual* issues? I'd recommend asking here instead, if you think it's a bug: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv

Comment: @slhck: No, not that I have noticed. I'm not sure at all if this is a bug or strictly related to mpv.

Comment: It's very likely that when you stream (via TCP) and quit MPV, it shuts down the ffmpeg process, which consequently cannot send a proper TCP close message. This is really not a problem or bug though.

Comment: @slhck No. the same happens in ffmpeg. This is a bug in Windows's openssl schannel: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/870bfe16a12bf09dca3a4ae27ef6f81a2de80c40/libavformat/tls_schannel.c#L494